# Xcode Deploy Multiple Targets to iOS Device

Tags: ios, xcode, target

When I select my target in Xcode and run it on my iPad it overwrites the other target in the same Xcode project. Is there a way to have both targets on the device simultaneously?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give them a different bundle ID in your info.plist.  This will require different mobile provisioning files for each target.  Most people have one target for debugging and development, and another for the production which strips out testing and debugging code.

Comment: Nice and simple, and thanks for the fast response. Big help! Can't even accept the answer for 2 minutes, but rest assured I will :)

Comment: As a related issue, I'm getting an error from having multiple targets where my storyboard has a custom view controller class, and it cannot find it in the new target unless I edit the module field to be the new target. Of course, doing this causes the bug to appear on the original target. Is there a way to stop this behaviour?

Comment: Your last comment really needs more information to go on.  You should post it as a separate question including the error description.